# Can I set Chrome to start Spotify from weblinks?

Tags: google-chrome, spotify

How can I set my Mac to open the Spotify application when I click on a weblink? While I have the appropriate preference set in Spotify...

[image]

... all Spotify URLs still open in the web player. (Almost always these are links friends send me over Facebook chat.)

I'm using Mavericks 10.9.2 and the most recent build of Chrome. (33.0.1750.146)

Comment: is that a Chrome extension we are talking about

Comment: No, the screenshot is from the Spotify application, and I'm talking about plain weblinks. Like this one: https://play.spotify.com/album/6316qgms0cRSXanY9meBSQ